# Run app on device on second app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, device, ipod

I've made my first application which ran fine on my iPod touch and on my iPad. Now I'm in the process of making my second app, but Xcode won't let me run the app on my device. When I plug in the device, it just does't pop up in the device menu (where you choose the simulator etc.), but it still works fine on my first app. Is there any additional configuration I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to be sure that you have installed a provisioning profile that match your application's identifier.

Check [Managing Devices and Digital Identities](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices_and_Digital_Identities/devices_and_identities.html)

Comment: I've followed the steps in the tutorial, but still can't get it to work.

Comment: Well, I've enabled the device for development. I've added it to the portal. It says it has the "Team provisioning profile: *", and I've also checked the "Automatic Device Provisioning".

Comment: What's strange is that I've just made a new project. The devices worked perfectly fine on my other project.

Comment: Ok, I feel a bit dumb now. It didn't show up because my deployment target was greater than my iOS firmware. <.< But thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Also, in the Xcode Organizer, you have to enable that device for Development (there's a medium size button button for that when you select the device in the Organizer). If you are using Xcode 4.1+ that device will automatically be provisioned for you.